# React app wont show up in browser, when properly started

Tags: docker, apache, npm, browser

I am trying to duplicate enviroment for already in use react app that works well. (The application is in production at the client's server and is being used daily).

I succesfuly run npm build and npm start . It should be accesible via port :3000 but its not. What can be a problem ?
Im operating at Docker container.

```
root@27fed68654af:/usr/local/apache2/htdocs# ss -tuln
Netid              State                Recv-Q               Send-Q                             Local Address:Port                              Peer Address:Port
udp                UNCONN               0                    0                                     127.0.0.11:36218                                  0.0.0.0:*
tcp                LISTEN               0                    128                                      0.0.0.0:80                                     0.0.0.0:*
tcp                LISTEN               0                    128                                   127.0.0.11:37105                                  0.0.0.0:*
tcp                LISTEN               0                    128                                      0.0.0.0:3000                                   0.0.0.0:*
```

Comment: Without a minimal code example it's hard to say what's causing the error.